# I want my compiled java class files to be in the same directory structure as my source files. How can I make Gradle do this?

Tags: java, gradle, build, build.gradle

I want Gradle to preserve the directory structure of my source java files when compiling them into class files.

Right now, my src directory looks like this:

```
--src
----helloworld.java
-----inner
-------byeworld.java
```

Right now, when I run the compileJava gradle task, all of these java files are lumped into the build/classes/java/main directory, like so:

```
build
--classes
----java
------main
--------helloworld.class
--------byeworld.class
```

I want it the result of compiling my class files to look like this:

```
build
--classes
----java
------main
--------helloworld.class
--------inner
----------byeworld.class
```

This is what my build.gradle file looks like right now:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

compileJava {
    options.fork = true
    options.incremental = true
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir '.'
        }
    }
}
```

Back when I was using Ant, as far as I could tell, the javac task automatically did this. How do I make Gradle replicate this behavior?

Comment: What package is `byeworld` in? I strongly suspect that's the problem. You should structure your source code to follow your package layout. Note that the compiler *has* to do that for class files, as otherwise the runtime won't be able to find classes.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks... you were right, putting byeworld in package 'inner' solved my problem. I'm not sure what to do now... if you put this in an answer, I will accept it.